# Assigning a 1D array into a 2D leads to incompatible types?

Tags: c

```
int solutions[92][81];

void add_solution(int board[81]) {
  solutions[found_sltns++] = board;
}
```

Code sample attached, I get

> error: incompatible types when
>   assigning to type ‘int[81]’ from type
>   ‘int’

when compiling

Any clue?

Comment: how are you calling the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't copy array in this manner. You have to perform a element by element copy.

```
int i;
for(i=0;i<81;i++)
 solutions[found_sltns][i] = board[i];
found_sltns++;
```

Comment: you probably mean board[i] :-)

Comment: @0x69: I think based in context, it should be solutions[found_sltns][i]

Comment: 0x69 means it should say solutions[found_sltns][i] = board[i];